# How can I capture the HWND of the last opened Explorer window before my PowerShell script console opens?

Tags: windows, powershell, window, hwnd, microsoft-file-explorer

I have a script that is invoked via right click context menu in Windows Explorer. I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want to capture the HWND of the window from which I invoked the script. Right now I have this:

```
Add-Type @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    public class Util {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    }
"@

$hwnd = [Util]::GetForegroundWindow()
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300
[void] [Util]::SetForegroundWindow($hwnd)
```

But it doesn't work because `$hwnd` gets assigned to the interactive console window when the script launches. I know I could probably hide the console using some kind of helper tool and that might work. But I'm wondering if there is a clean way or some kind of buried method to capture the correct explorer window.

Hopefully this makes sense. Any help appreciated.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57136189/45375) helps, If so, we can close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: That link went above and beyond what I expected, thank you so much. Feel free to close this as a duplicate.